# Find which one of a list of patterns is matched by a given string

Tags: string, data-structures, language-agnostic, pattern-matching, wildcard

I have a fixed unknown set of pattern strings, which use the wildcards `*` and `?` (`?` = one character, `*` = zero or more characters). For example:

- `"abcd?"`
- `"dogcat*"`
- `"*car"`
- `"hello*world"`

I want to generate some data structure out of these patterns, that has a method called `findPattern`. The method accepts a string which is guaranteed to match at most one of the patterns, and returns the pattern to which the string matches (if any).

In the above example:

- `findPattern("abcde")` returns `"abcd?"`
- `findPattern("hellocar")` returns `"*car"`
- `findPattern("edbca")` returns `null`

A string such as `"dogcatfrogcar"` is guaranteed not to be given as input for this method.

Building the data structure can be slow, since the pattern set is given once. The function will be called for many strings on the same pattern set, so it needs to be efficient.

How do I achieve this?

P.S. I'm programming-language agnostic

Comment: I'm a little out of time to elaborate more, but what you need is to create a non-deterministic finite automaton. Assuming a pattern with n chars and a string with m chars, you can either run it against directly your string with an O(n*m) cost for each string, or transform it to a deterministic finite automaton with O(2^n) states, but with a matching cost of O(m).

Comment: Yes this seems to be the right direction. Do you know any libraries that implement something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Aho-Corasic algorithm is intended to find multiple patterns in the text. Fortunately, [it is possible to work with '?' wildcards](http://www.cs.uku.fi/~kilpelai/BSA05/lectures/slides04.pdf) (single symbols), and *"If the number of wild cards is bounded by a constant, patterns with wild-cards can be matched in linear time"*

Comment: +1 - That's a nice idea, but too limited for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

We can replace each pattern with a regular expression and try to solve a more general problem.

In that case I have found to interesting approaches:

1. The [RE2 library](http://code.google.com/p/re2/), which allows matching several regular expressions simultaneously (as long as they don't have back references, which is the case here) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869003/566639).
2. [Lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) and Lex-like lexical analyzers - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900598/566639).